# What's wrong with my way of using filter_input?

Tags: php

I am told that I should use filter_input rather than accessing $_SERVER directly

So I made this simple 2 line of code

```
    echo "filter:input " . filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'REMOTE_ADDR');
    echo "SERVER:" .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;
```

Very simple. I expect they both produce the exact same thing.

This is what I got

filter:input SERVER:202.80.212.17

Clearly filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'REMOTE_ADDR') produces empty string.

Why?

Comment: Which php version are you using? Meanwhile you can always use `filter_input($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` to achieve the same.

Comment: Edit: It is related http://stackoverflow.com/q/25316085/1415724

Comment: Duplicate or not the answer for this question is just awesome

Comment: Jim Thio strikes again lol.  Showing contempt for Stacks by not looking to see if things are answered already, and then posting basically a "who cares" response to a question being marked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a bug in older versions of php. You can either use

```
echo "filter:input " . filter_input(INPUT_ENV, 'REMOTE_ADDR', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

Or use

```
echo "filter:input " . filter_input($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: filter_input (INPUT_ENV doesn't work on my debugging environment. It should at least show ::1. guess I am back to REMOTE_ADDR